# Как создать домашнюю сеть?

Tags: сеть, router, wifi

Как можно соединить два ноутбука с интернетом, если на первом ноуте стоит ОС `WinXP`, и он подключен к интернету через `LAN`. Второй ноутбук соединяется с ним через `wi-fi`; ОС может быть любая. Есть ли какая-нибудь программа для этих целей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы не хотите тратить деньги и у Вас хватит терпения держать второй ноут включенным, когда на первом надо пользвоаться интернетом - предоставление доступа к интернету стандартная функция подключения peer-to-peer по wi-fi в Windows.

P.S.
К сожалению, не использую Windows, но Microsoft любезно написал [инструкцию](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126/ru).

Comment: А можно по-подробнее как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Самый оптимальный на мой взгляд вариант, это купить свитч с поддержкой Wi-Fi. Создавая сети с использованием прокси (для дома), вы создаёте себе необходимость всегда держать компьютер выполняющий роль сервера включенным. Что не всегда удобно.

Comment: Только скорее всего, потребуется не свитч, а роутер.

Answer (score 0):

платный (25-30$), но в итоге безгеморройный вариант -- купить роутер с ТД WiFi, например TP-Link 340G.
Настраивается однократно и работает долго.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант установить и настроить прокси сервер на ПК с интернет. К примеру HandyCache, Squid или 3proxy. А на втором ПК в настройках указать IP и порт первого ПК в адрес прокси.